# Edit profile the triangle just keeps spinning

Tags: installation

I am using a new install of 4.6 with no additional plugins installed.  I go to contributions>manage contibution pages > member Sign up> Configure then profiles. I click the edit edit button next to any of the dropdowns and the triangle page pops up and just spins. I have to refresh and start over.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Hi Gary. Presuming you meant eg here. http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/contribute/custom?reset=1&action=update&id=1 (regardless of whether we are talking D, WP or J) - and then using the EDIT next to a Profile that you select. I was about to say "to avoid the pop up, right click and open the EDIT in a new tab" but i see that doesn't work. Alternate approach, go to the Profile page at http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/uf/group?reset=1. Also try Inspect on that page and see if there are some js errors etc

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a javascript error. Try going through the following troubleshooting steps:

[Troubleshooting popups, autocompletes, or other javascript problems.](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=35850.0)

Comment: wow @coleman - that post should be one of the mkdocs!

Answer (score 0):

Check console error for more details. Most of the time it's happened because jaisey version or cIvicrm cache issue. Check after clearing the civicrm cache or jquery version change.